# http get response in scope with ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a controller in AngularJS that calls http.get to an API, and returns a 0 (for now). I managed to display 0 on the console without problems, but I can not display it in the $scope on the front.

**App.js**

```
.controller('ssnGenAltaCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http){
        $scope.generarRubricaAlta = function(data){
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'url'
            }).then(function successCallback(data) {
                console.log(data.data);
                $scope.mensaje = data.data;
            }, function errorCallback(data) {
                console.log("Error");
            });
        }
    }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" ng-click="generarRubricaAlta()">Generar Rubrica Alta</a>
    <p class="bg-primary">{{mensaje}}</p>
</div>
```

**Routing**

```
.when("/ssnGenAlta", {
    templateUrl : "views/ssnGenAlta.html",
    controller: "ssnGenAltaCtrl"
})
```

**JSON Output**

```
Object
config: Object
data: "0"
headers: (d)
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you set up the right ng-app and ng-controller in the html?

Comment: @mnemosdev yes, in fact the button in the HTML works without problems, and I get the HTTP response in the console, but not in the front.

Comment: Can you show the output for console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: Although not working, you do see the template view for ssnGenAlta.html?

Comment: Yes, but you said that the HTML shows just fine. Problem is in interpolation the response to the DOM, Right?

Comment: Maybe you need to add an additional callback function because you are able to see the data when console.log(data) from inside the successCallback. Try to create the $scope.mensaje variable outside of your cb

Comment: @JSNinja I added the json output to the post. I'm not seeing the HTML structure in the view, in fact when I click in the button and the 0 appear in the console, the button did disappear.

Comment: @mnemosdev I did some test and when I enter the HTML, I can see without problem the HTML structure, but when the button is clicked the view disappear and I cant get the HTML response in the view. I think that the problem is in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the anchor tag:

The href attribute redirects to #

```
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-default" x:ng:href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" ng-click="generarRubricaAlta()">Generar Rubrica Alta</a>
    <p class="bg-primary">{{mensaje}}</p>
</div>
```

Replace it with x:ng:href="javascript:void(0)"

Also initialize 
`$scope.mensaje = "123";` before method declaration

Check if two way binding works or not.
If it does, change back to `$scope.mensaje = "";`

```
.controller('ssnGenAltaCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http){
    $scope.mensaje = "123"; //change this back to empty string
    $scope.generarRubricaAlta = function(data){
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'url'
        }).then(function successCallback(data) {
            console.log(data.data);
            $scope.mensaje = data.data;
        }, function errorCallback(data) {
            console.log("Error");
        });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Remove the data argument from the method generarRubricaAlta()

Comment: wp mate, nice catch

Comment: OK, I tried that and it didn't work. The $scope.mensaje is not showing, and the view keeps disappearing. I'm creating a jsfiddle.

Comment: Jsfiddle is a no-go, sorry. But the problem is definitely in the button, because with a ng-init="generarRubricaAlta()" I can see the 0 in the front wit no issues.

Comment: try ng:href instead of href

Comment: Yes! Finally! ng:ref="javascript:void(0)" is the answer! Thank you very much @JSNinja!

Comment: Your welcome. ng:href interpolates the value passed to it

Answer (score 0):

code was current, I think you just need to define variable before API calling

```
.controller('ssnGenAltaCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http){
$scope.mensaje = {};//you need to define variable before API calling for 2way data binding. 
    $scope.generarRubricaAlta = function(data){
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'url'
        }).then(function successCallback(data) {
            console.log(data.data);
            $scope.mensaje = data.data;
        }, function errorCallback(data) {
            console.log("Error");
        });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: data.data is a string and not an object.